# ImportError: Entry point ('zc.buildout', 'default') not found

Tags: python, debian, plone, buildout

I'm trying to install Plumi 4.5.1 which is based on Plone.

Target system is a 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64  (Debian GNU/Linux 8)

I'm following this guide:

https://mgogoulos.trinket.io/plumi-4-5#/installation/installation

and after doing all prior steps successfully, i get this error while running buildout:

[..]

```
We have the distribution that satisfies 'py==1.3.4'.
Getting required 'pyasn1'
  required by collective.transcode.daemon 0.12.
We have the best distribution that satisfies 'pyasn1'.
Picked: pyasn1 = 0.1.8
Getting required 'Twisted'
  required by collective.transcode.daemon 0.12.
We have the best distribution that satisfies 'Twisted'.
Picked: Twisted = 15.2.1
Getting required 'pycrypto==2.4.1'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'pycrypto==2.4.1'.
Installing 'plone.recipe.varnish'.
We have the best distribution that satisfies 'plone.recipe.varnish'.
Picked: plone.recipe.varnish = 2.0a1
Getting required 'jinja2>=2.7.3'
  required by plone.recipe.varnish 2.0a1.
We have the best distribution that satisfies 'jinja2>=2.7.3'.
Picked: Jinja2 = 2.7.3
Getting required 'markupsafe'
  required by Jinja2 2.7.3.
We have the best distribution that satisfies 'markupsafe'.
Picked: MarkupSafe = 0.23
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section cache.
  Initializing section cache.
  Loading zc.buildout recipe entry plone.recipe.varnish:default.

An internal error occured due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/plumi/PLUMI/plumi.app/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1683, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/home/plumi/PLUMI/plumi.app/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 439, in install
    [self[part]['recipe'] for part in install_parts]
  File "/home/plumi/PLUMI/plumi.app/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 987, in __getitem__
    options._initialize()
  File "/home/plumi/PLUMI/plumi.app/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1071, in _initialize
    recipe_class = _install_and_load(reqs, 'zc.buildout', entry, buildout)
  File "/home/plumi/PLUMI/plumi.app/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1032, in _install_and_load
    req.project_name, group, entry)
  File "/home/plumi/PLUMI/plumi.app/eggs/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/plumi/PLUMI/plumi.app/eggs/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2306, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('zc.buildout', 'default') not found
*********************************************
Overwriting versions.cfg
*********************************************
```

Is there anything i can do or check ?

I did not touch anything in the configuration of the buildout so everything is "default".

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by adding the following:

```
zc.buildout = 1.7.1
distribute = 0.6.35
```

In section:

```
[versions]
```

Of the file `buildout.cfg` file of the Plumi/Plone deployment folder.